# Problem with RandomSearch option

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Solving an optimization problem with `Method->"RandomSearch"` option

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; n = 10;
NMaximize[{-Sum[p[k]*Log[p[k]], {k, 1, n}],Sum[p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 1 && Sum[k*p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 2 && 
p[1] > 0 && p[2] > 0,  p[3] > 0 && p[4] > 0 && p[5] > 0 && p[6] > 0 && p[7] > 0 && 
p[8] > 0 && p[9] > 0 && p[10] > 0}, Table[p[k], {k, 1, n}], Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 100}]enter code here
```

, I obtain a warning

> NMaximize::nrnum: The function value -1.22046-0.408196 I is not a real number at {p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5],p[6],p[7],p[8],p[9],p[10]} = {0.598474,0.1655,0.000789021,<<4>>,0.0343533,0.0636326,-0.129933}.

and an incorrect result

> `{-Log[p[2]] p[2] - Log[p[3]] p[3] - Log[p[4]] p[4] - Log[p[5]] p[5] -  Log[p[6]] p[6] - Log[p[7]] p[7] - Log[p[8]] p[8] -  Log[0.111111 - 0.111111 p[2] - 0.222222 p[3] - 0.333333 p[4] -  0.444444 p[5] - 0.555556 p[6] - 0.666667 p[7] - 0.777778 p[8] -  0.888889 p[9]] (0.111111 - 0.111111 p[2] - 0.222222 p[3] -  0.333333 p[4] - 0.444444 p[5] - 0.555556 p[6] - 0.666667 p[7] -  0.777778 p[8] - 0.888889 p[9]) -  Log[0.888889 - 0.888889 p[2] - 0.777778 p[3] - 0.666667 p[4] -  0.555556 p[5] - 0.444444 p[6] - 0.333333 p[7] - 0.222222 p[8] -  0.111111 p[9]] (0.888889 - 0.888889 p[2] - 0.777778 p[3] -  0.666667 p[4] - 0.555556 p[5] - 0.444444 p[6] - 0.333333 p[7] -  0.222222 p[8] - 0.111111 p[9]) -  Log[p[9]] p[9], {p[1] -> 0.598474, p[2] -> 0.1655,  p[3] -> 0.000789021, p[4] -> 0.0231708, p[5] -> 0.0453707,  p[6] -> 0.190066, p[7] -> 0.00857625, p[8] -> 0.0343533,  p[9] -> 0.0636326, p[10] -> -0.129933}}`

The same issue with the  `Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"` option. The following works properly.

```
NMaximize[{-Sum[p[k]*Log[p[k]], {k, 1, n}],  Sum[p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 1 && Sum[k*p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 2 && 
p[1] > 0 && p[2] > 0, p[3] > 0 && p[4] > 0 && p[5] > 0 && p[6] > 0 && p[7] > 0 && 
p[8] > 0 && p[9] > 0 && p[10] > 0}, Table[p[k], {k, 1, n}]]
```

> `{1.3853, {p[1] -> 0.497951, p[2] -> 0.250251, p[3] -> 0.125766,  p[4] -> 0.063205, p[5] -> 0.0317643, p[6] -> 0.0159635,  p[7] -> 0.00802259, p[8] -> 0.00403182, p[9] -> 0.00202621,  p[10] -> 0.00101827}}`

How to make the `RandomSearch` and `DifferentialEvolution` options  work properly?

Comment: Moreover,`n = 12; NMaximize[{-Sum[
    p[k]*Log[RealAbs[p[k]]], {k, 1, n}], 
  Sum[p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 1 && Sum[k*p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 2 && 
   Table[p[k], {k, 1, n}] > 0}, Table[p[k], {k, 1, n}], 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]` results in

Comment: `{1.4282892260442467457, {p[1] -> 0.4425246563389881153, 
  p[2] -> 0.29444691323000000558, p[3] -> 0.12572534947384017300, 
  p[4] -> 0.077676590570172439455, p[5] -> 0.027188684208537776711, 
  p[6] -> 0.021795299720855472760, p[7] -> 0.0098369941067331116801, 
  p[8] -> 0.0099145281647085854905, p[9] -> 0.0063505406743991386861, 
  p[10] -> 0.0029157117376203413588, 
  p[11] -> 6.1669354330318860399*10^-8, 
  p[12] -> -0.01837532989520949036}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid roundoff errors in the functional change `Log[p[k]]` to `Log[RealAbs[p[k]]]`

```
n = 10;

Table[
NMaximize[{-Sum[p[k]*Log[RealAbs[p[k]]], {k, 1, n}],Sum[p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 1 && Sum[k*p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 2 && 
 p[1] > 0 && p[2] > 0,p[3] > 0 && p[4] > 0 && p[5] > 0 && p[6] > 0 && p[7] > 0 &&p[8] > 0 && p[9] > 0 && p[10] > 0}, Table[p[k], {k, 1, n}], 
 Method -> {Automatic, "NelderMead", "RandomSearch" ,"DifferentialEvolution"  }[[i]] ] // Quiet
 , {i, 1, 4}]

(*{{1.37947, {p[1] -> 0.486356, p[2] -> 0.260099, p[3] -> 0.131519, p[4] -> 0.0550347, p[5] -> 0.041031, p[6] -> 0.0128654, p[7] -> 0.0056115, p[8] -> 0.00788751, p[9] -> 0.00193489,p[10] -> -0.00233915}}, 
{1.37947, {p[1] -> 0.486356,p[2] -> 0.260099, p[3] -> 0.131519, p[4] -> 0.0550347,p[5] -> 0.041031, p[6] -> 0.0128654, p[7] -> 0.0056115,p[8] -> 0.00788751, p[9] -> 0.00193489,p[10] -> -0.00233915}}, 
{1.38529, {p[1] -> 0.497953,p[2] -> 0.250251, p[3] -> 0.125766, p[4] -> 0.0632046,p[5] -> 0.031764, p[6] -> 0.0159633, p[7] -> 0.00802249,p[8] -> 0.00403177, p[9] -> 0.0020262,p[10] -> 0.00101829}}, 
{1.38302, {p[1] -> 0.501038,p[2] -> 0.257196, p[3] -> 0.114503, p[4] -> 0.0613219,p[5] -> 0.0347692, p[6] -> 0.0149038, p[7] -> 0.00576647,p[8] -> 0.00478949, p[9] -> 0.00330252, p[10] -> 0.00241029}}}*)
```

**addendum**

Unfortunately solutions of the first two methods doesn't fullfill the constraints (`p[10]<0` )

Further restriction of the parameterranges to `0<p[k]<1` gives similar plausible results for the 4 methods:

```
n = 10;
Table[NMaximize[{-Sum[p[k]*Log[RealAbs[p[k]]], {k, 1, n}], 
Sum[p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 1, Sum[k*p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 2, 
Map[0 < # < 1 &, Table[p[k], {k, 1, n}]]}, Table[p[k], {k, 1,n}], 
Method -> {Automatic, "NelderMead", "RandomSearch","DifferentialEvolution"}[[i]]] 
, {i, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: The output without `Quit` produces `{{1.37947, {p[1] -> 0.486356, p[2] -> 0.260099, p[3] -> 0.131519, 
   p[4] -> 0.0550347, p[5] -> 0.041031, p[6] -> 0.0128654, 
   p[7] -> 0.0056115, p[8] -> 0.00788751, p[9] -> 0.00193489, 
   p[10] -> -0.00233915}}, {1.37947, {p[1] -> 0.486356, 
   p[2] -> 0.260099, p[3] -> 0.131519, p[4] -> 0.0550347, 
   p[5] -> 0.041031, p[6] -> 0.0128654, p[7] -> 0.0056115, 
   p[8] -> 0.00788751, p[9] -> 0.00193489, p[10] -> -0.00233915}},`

Comment: `{1.38529, {p[1] -> 0.497953, p[2] -> 0.250251, p[3] -> 0.125766, 
   p[4] -> 0.0632046, p[5] -> 0.031764, p[6] -> 0.0159633, 
   p[7] -> 0.00802249, p[8] -> 0.00403177, p[9] -> 0.0020262, 
   p[10] -> 0.00101829}}, {1.38302, {p[1] -> 0.501038, 
   p[2] -> 0.257196, p[3] -> 0.114503, p[4] -> 0.0613219, 
   p[5] -> 0.0347692, p[6] -> 0.0149038, p[7] -> 0.00576647, 
   p[8] -> 0.00478949, p[9] -> 0.00330252, p[10] -> 0.00241029}}}`. and a lot of warnings.Pay your attention to the incorrect results of `Automatic` and`HealderMead` and a variance in the results.. This is not it.

Comment: @user64494 My answer shows you a way how to make `NMaximize` work  for RandomSearch and DifferentialEvolution options . That's what you asked for!

Comment: The cure is not better than the disease. I am right, aren't I?

Comment: `n = 12; NMaximize[{-Sum[
    p[k]*Log[RealAbs[p[k]]], {k, 1, n}], 
  Sum[p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 1 && Sum[k*p[k], {k, 1, n}] == 2 && 
   p[1] > 0 && p[2] > 0, 
  p[3] > 0 && p[4] > 0 && p[5] > 0 && p[6] > 0 && p[7] > 0 && 
   p[8] > 0 && p[9] > 0 && p[10] > 0 && p[11] > 0 && p[12] > 0}, 
 Table[p[k], {k, 1, n}], Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]` performs

Comment: `{1.38732, {p[1] -> 0.498584, p[2] -> 0.254054, p[3] -> 0.115688, 
  p[4] -> 0.0619728, p[5] -> 0.0402178, p[6] -> 0.0118743, 
  p[7] -> 0.00743202, p[8] -> 0.00763983, p[9] -> 0.00496901, 
  p[10] -> 0.00123952, p[11] -> 0.000178143, p[12] -> -0.00385019}}`. Pay your attention to the sign of `p[12]`. This is not it.

Comment: The option `WorkingPrecision -> 20` in the above code does not help.

Comment: For `n=12` the modified code produces incorrect results for `Automatic` and `NelderMead` and fails with `RandomSearch`. The output with `DifferentialEvolution" `is not satisfactory in view of `p[10] -> 2.57056*10^-8, p[11] -> 6.35807*10^-8, p[12] -> 0.000164199`(These probabilities should decrease.). Think of `n>12`.

Comment: For `n=11` three incorrect results and one returned input.

Comment: Your code answers my question so I should to accept it. However, the one doesn't work for bigger values of `n`. I'd like to suggest to MMA developers that the returned output is better than an incorrect one.

Comment: I am curious about the answer of MMA